# Unit test for missing migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Can you write an unit test that verifies that all migration scripts are generated?

I wanted to implement this so the CI build fails when someone forgets to `Add-Migration`. But the ef core in-memory DB does not allow any "relational-specific" stuff and the SqLite DB fails because "no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory", which seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9842) that won't be fixed.

I was also looking into the generated snapshot and if there is any way to compare this to my current code-base, but did not find anything helpful.

This test should be lightweight and run without an real DB.

Answer (score 0):

A kind of hackish solution would be comparing the `Migrations/*Snapshot.cs` before and after running `dotnet ef migrations add <migration>`.

I think this could work:

```
before="$(sha256sum Migrations/*Snapshot.cs | sha256sum)"
dotnet ef migrations add dummy
after="$(sha256sum Migrations/*Snapshot.cs | sha256sum)"
if [ "$before" != "$after" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```